# Динамическое отображение файлов (Nuxt.js)

Tags: nuxt.js

Написал веб-приложение на Nuxt.js (библиотека книг .pdf) с админ панелью, где пользователь может посмотреть каталог книг, а администратор (в админке) может добавить новую книгу, отредактировать название уже добавленной, удалить и т.д. Вопрос в том, что как я понял во время nuxt build приложение собирает все мои файлы и записывает все в _nuxt/dust, вместе с моими pdf-файлами, которые я храню в папке static (что возможно неправильно), и после билда приложения, когда админ добавляет новую книгу с файлом, (этого файла уже не будет папке _nuxt/dist). Есть ли способ слежения за изменением static или какие-то настройки nuxt.config для решения этой проблемы без ребилда приложения после добавления новой книги? Спасибо!

Comment: А почему не сохранять файлы в папку static? Она всегда доступна, пересобирать проект не нужно. Создайте папку static/uploads и туда грузите файлы

Comment: В режиме npm run dev все работает, т.е. когда в админке добавляешь новый файл, то он сохраняется в static и у пользователя он отображается, но когда я делаю npm run build и добавляю новый файл в админке, то у пользователя выводится ошибка "Cannot find module"

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, проблема была в настройке вебпака, он при билде проекта собирал все pdf в assets